# Android file transfer without SD card

Tags: android

I'm trying to copy my app to an Android phone without an SD card. I've tried bluetooth and I've tried email attachment, but both of them seem to require an SD card for the download to take place. Is there any other way to do this without having an SD card at hand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I frequently deploy to my phone using the eclipse IDE.  Assuming the drivers for your phone are installed on your PC you can connect your phone with a USB cable and simply run the application in debug mode and it will deploy to your phone.

I've also emailed an app to my phone and then install it from my email.  Are you certain you have allowed apps to be installed from unknown sources?  If you have not you will need to do so.

Comment: Ah, didn't know we could deploy to the phone using Eclipse! Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a procedure if this is from eclipse.
In your project>Bin>file.apk assuming eclipse
send the file.apk file to your phone.
Use an app installer to install the file.apk to your phone.
There you go a copy of your program

Answer (score 0):

In my experience neither the mail client app or anything that imply a download from a website from the browser have being able to install the APKs without compying it on an SDCard before.
The only solution I got working so far would be to open the APK from the Google Drive app.

I suppose other network drive services could works as well but never had occasion to try them out.